# Elasticsearch Terms Aggregation - Integer field

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Basically I have a catalog setup in es, and each category has an id (int) and it's name as a string.

I have a facet currently working to get the categories by their id and count them to show them in a 'filter' type display on the site.

Anyways, facets are apparently depreciated so it says to use a terms aggregation on the site.

I put in the following code ('catList' is a list in the main doc, hence nested):

```
.Aggregations
(a => a.Nested
    ("agg_cat",
    n => n.Path("catList")
    .Aggregations(aa => aa.Terms("level1", st => st.Field("categoryLevel1ID")))))
```

(using 'nest' in .net).

It works in the sense that it gets back the items in their buckets and gets the correct count etc, but the *'key' field is 'null'*.

**Question:** can I get the 'key' field back with the integer in it?

Currently I have a 'work around' re changing the mapping from a 'integer' to a 'multi_field' with two 'fields' a string and an integer. If I change the aggregation to the string field then in the 'key' I get back the number (as a string...). Works because I can just in the .net code convert to int, but it feels kind of hackish.... Does anyone see any problems with this approach?

Ps: reading the [term agg](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) doc on the elasticsearch site, I can't see anything about it being only useable for strings. Is this missing?

ES version: 1.3.2 (downloaded 30min ago :P)

Comment: Which version of NEST you were using?

Comment: checked svn as it was a while ago..... 1.0.0.0